# Adding Runtime VM parameters to intellij for Java 9

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, jaxb

I am using IntelliJ to build a spring boot project in Java 9.
But I'm getting 
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException`
whenever i use `@SpringBootTest` or `@DataJpaTest`.

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j) I added `--add-modules=java.xml.bind` in the **Run Configuration - VM options** which fixed the problem but only for that Run Configuration on which I added it.

Now i have multiple Test Classes that make use of `@SpringBootTest` or `@DataJpaTest` and if I manually go and add the `--add-modules=java.xml.bind` to each Run Configuration, each on works individually but when i try to for example

`src/test/java -> right click and Run Tests` (on the whole test suite)

- it doesn't consider those individual Run Configuration and hence fails for those tests,

Is there any option to add the VM options - so that they are considered during integration test runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this finally worked for me

Use case:  selecting the whole src/test/java package by right clicking - and being able to run all tests

In IntelliJ

1. Create a new run configuration of JUnit
2. There you will see an option - Test Kind - select All in package
3. then choose Search for Tests in whole project
4. and then define your vm options 
   [image: sample]

Note: this is for my use case , i still need to define this vm option if i want to run tests individually, but i think it can also be configured in Maven Surefire plugin. 
But for now this solved my problem.